# How to withdraw all tokens form my bsc contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, erc20

I'm really really inexperienced with contracts and need your help. I created a contract with remix and sent some bnb to it. I want to retrieve it but I can't seem to make it happen.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {
    function withdrawToken(address _tokenContract, uint256 _amount) external {
        IERC20 tokenContract = IERC20(_tokenContract);
        
        // transfer the token from address of this contract
        // to address of the user (executing the withdrawToken() function)
        tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
}
```

This is the code that I'm using from another post but I don't understand it. Do I have to change the "_to" "and "_amount" with the numbers or do I just copy the code and compile it?

I'm really sorry but I have no idea what I did so I just want to take the tokens back.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you can't withdraw your bnb, bnb isn't a token, bnb is like the ether in ethereum, the native chain currency and the contract doesn't have a function to let you withdraw it, the only way is if you send wbnb, in that case you can look the address of the contract of the wbnb and call the function withdraw of the contract you made

Answer (score 0):

As Jhonny said, BNB is not an actual token, and so your implemented logic won't work to withdraw BNB. But just for you to know, you could create a function which only allows withdrawing BNB (which is the native currency). It would be something like this:

```
function withdraw(uint _amount) external {
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);    
}
```

Hope you find this useful.